# autohotkey how to remap mouse left click hold action

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to change the input of a mouse when I click the left button and hold it.
The usual left click action must remain. Let left click behave as it is, but if you click and hold, let it perform something like holding keyboard button P (or any other keyboard button).

Currently what I got is something like:

```
~LButton:: 
sleep 100
While (Getkeystate("LButton","P"))
{   

    Send, {M down}

}
Send, {M up}

Return
```

I am trying to figure out how to remove the click action when I want just to  spam letter M.

Comment: Are you aware that your request would disable things like drag and drop/move or high lighting text with your mouse. Is this something you have thought about?

Comment: Yes I am aware. I just need this script to run while I play a game. Updated the question with what I got so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
threshold := 100
LButton::
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen ; needed to prevent some issues when clicking changes focus
    MouseGetPos, mXclick, mYclick ; save mouse position before sleep

    sleep % threshold

    ; mouse up, do normal click
    if (!GetKeyState("LButton", "P")) {
        MouseGetPos, mXcurr, mYcurr ; save mouse position before click
        Click %mXclick%, %mYclick%
        MouseMove, %mXcurr%, %mYCurr% ; restore mouse position
        return
    }

    while (GetKeyState("LButton", "P")) {
        Send {M down}
        Sleep 30
    }
    Send {M up}
return
```

You can play with the `threshold`, try different values and see how it works. Also all the `MouseGetPos` and `MouseMove` might not be needed, depends on what you want to happen.

Currently doubleClick will also be a little problematic, you need to doubleClick slower than the `threshold` but fast enough to register a doubleClick. This can probably be solved, so tell me if it's something you need.

Comment: Oleg thank you for your code. What I am trying to accomplish is dragging function in a game. Dragging can be assigned to any key on the keyboard. I do assign dragging to the letter M. Your code is very helpful. It helped me understand that threshold is very important and it will be almost impossible to set it perfect. There will be a delay in click itself.

Comment: @IamMashed np, if you want one click to do 2 different things then yes the solution can only be time based. Also it looks like you might have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) if this is the case you should also ask another question about the X, maybe somebody will figure out a solution for you.